# Charge a Novatel 4G hotspot via a computer without turning the WiFi off

Tags: macos, usb

I have a Novatel 4G hotspot (Verizon 4510L). When I plug it into the USB port on my computer for charging, the computer "recognizes" it (shows up in Hardware), and I cannot connect to it. If it's not plugged into a port (or plugged in to the wall), it works perfectly. I imagine I'd need special drivers to use it as a network device, which are not anywhere to be found.

Is there any way to get the hotspot to not react like this, either from the OSX side or from the device side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Peter Maxwell's answer is totally right on, but the link is missing information.

> The procedure to modify the cable is missing a step to make it work
>   for the 4510L. You need to tie the data lines (green and white wires)
>   together on the micro USB end. Leave the USB (computer side) wires
>   open. Connecting the data lines together makes the 4510L think that a
>   charger is connected.

This is from this [Verizon Forum Thread](http://community.vzw.com/t5/Broadband-Netbook-Devices/4G-LTE-Mobile-Hotspot-MiFi-4510L-Can-t-Charge-and-Use/td-p/522120/page/2) (where Verizon shows its true colors as a bunch of bungling idiots).

What he means is that on the micro-USB side, you have to strip off the ends of the green and white cables and tie them together. I just tried it and it works! (for some reason I have a wire stripper, but otherwise I guess you could use your teeth.)

Note that they can't touch ground (the metal stuff surrounding the wires), which means you need to use the electrical tape more creatively, or something...

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a known issue.
http://www.phonearena.com/reviews/Novatel-4510L-4G-MiFi-for-Verizon-Wireless-Review_id2722

> But when we connected the Novatel 4510L to a PC via a microUSB data
>   cable, it would restart the MiFi and charge it and the Wi-Fi
>   connection would be disabled, thus not allowing any devices to use it
>   for data. We even pressed the power button, which did show the device
>   turn on, and the display showed the signal strength, but it still
>   would not transmit over Wi-Fi.

But you could do [this](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/2146) to make a charge only cable.

Comment: Both parts of the answer are awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: thanks, in practice the second part of the answer was close but not enough. The charging cable also has green and white wires connected together.

Comment: New answer: update the firmware for the modem :)